# Android error logs, activities in manifest, FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Tags: android, post, error-handling, android-asynctask, android-manifest

Another android question, I am trying to post data from an edittext on my app to a script on the server but am running into one error after another. Here is what i now have

```
package com.college.slimandsave;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FoodSearchActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


    public ListView list;
    public Button btnSearch;
    private static EditText txtFoodSearch;
    private ProgressBar pb;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_search);        
        txtFoodSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFoodSearch);   

       // txtFoodSearch = txtFoodSearch.getText().toString();

        btnSearch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);        
        // btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        pb =(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu); // check this
                return true;
            }

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(txtFoodSearch.getText().toString().length()<1) {

                    Toast.makeText(this , "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    new MyAsyncTask().execute(txtFoodSearch.getText().toString());
                }

            }

        private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,  Integer, Double>{


        String fsearch = txtFoodSearch.getText().toString();

            @Override
            protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {

                postData(params[0]);
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "search sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
            }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress) {
                pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
            }

            public void postData(String fsearch) {
                //create new http client
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("192.168.133.84/SlimandSave/try.php");

                try {
                    //add data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", fsearch));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    //execute HTTP post request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                }   catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                }   catch (IOException e) {

                }
            }
        }

}
```

and my manifest is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.college.slimandsave"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.college.slimandsave.HomeScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.college.slimandsave.StatsScreenActivity" 
            android:label="@string/lblStatsScreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.college.slimandsave.FoodDiaryActivity"
            android:label="@string/lblFoodDiary" >
        </activity>          
        <activity 
            android:name="com.college.slimandsave.SlimAndSaveActivity" 
            android:label="@string/Slim_And_Save" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.college.slimandsave.AboutScreenActivity" 
            android:label="@string/lblAbout" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.college.slimandsave.FoodSearchActivity" 
            android:label="@string/lblFoodSearch" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.college.slimandsave.GetItemsActivity" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>


    </application>




</manifest>
```

and finally the error log.

```
    02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=192.168.133.84/SlimandSave/try.php
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at com.college.slimandsave.FoodSearchActivity$MyAsyncTask.postData(FoodSearchActivity.java:106)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at com.college.slimandsave.FoodSearchActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(FoodSearchActivity.java:81)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at com.college.slimandsave.FoodSearchActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(FoodSearchActivity.java:1)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-19 08:49:25.019: E/AndroidRuntime(5574):     ... 5 more
```

Edit..... the above is my latest code and error log. On the php side I just have a fileputcontents to write to a text file.

Edit... adding http:// before the ip address seemed to work and instead of using the fSearch string in the namevalue pair i used txtFoodSearch.getText().toString().

Comment: Thanks, based on the below I think I will roll back to where I was before I began making changes today. I have found a good tutorial similar to what i want to achieve so I will follow this more closely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SearchActivity` is not a Activity class

And you have

```
Intent intSearch = new Intent(FoodSearchActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
startActivity(intSearch);
```

Its a AsyncTask class

```
public static class SearchActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
```

To invoke Asynctask use

```
new SearchActivity().execute(params);
```

Your `doInbackground` does nothing.

You have network operation in `postData(View v)` which should go in `doInbackground`

Also you have

```
 <activity android:name="com.college.slimandsave.FoodSearchActivity$SearchActivity" >    
 </activity>
```

which should be removed.